# Specify queue for a Task class in Celery

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

When I create a function task, I can do the following to specify the queue:

```
@app.task(name='my_task', queue='my_queue')
def some_task():
    return "hey"
```

Then, I can call this task like this: `some_task.delay()` and it would send the task to the `my_queue`.

However, if I have a class that inherits from the `celery.Task` class, I have to specify the queue every time I call this task:

```
class MyTask(Task):
    def run(self):
        return "Hey"

MyTask.apply_async(queue="my_queue")
```

Is there a way to specify this in the class definition? Something like this:

```
class MyTask(Task):
    queue = 'my_queue'

    def run(self):
         return "Hey"
```

I cannot find a way to do it in the documentation. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

Turns out, that was exactly how you would do it:

```
class MyTask(Task):
    queue = 'my_queue'

    def run(self):
        return "Hey"
```

Comment: Is there a documentation describing that this kind of override is possible? I was unable to find it.